# Improve bisection method or alternate algorithm for efficient determination of text font size to fit in a box

Tags: algorithms

I need to find the font size of a text that fits in a box.

Given my current font size, I can get the bounding rectangle of the text.

If I set some arbitrary min and max font size, I suppose I can increment or decrement my font size until I get to the given box.

I am thinking bisection method:

```
ChangeFontMethod(float currentFont, float reqWidth)

    float minFont = 1, maxFont = 1000
    int tolerance = 0.001, maxIter = 1000 
    int n = 1

    float currentWidth = textWithCurrentFont.boundingRect.Width

    do
        if currentWidth = reqWidth
            break
        else if currentWidth < reqWidth
            minFont = currentFont
        else
            maxFont = currentFont

        if maxFont - minFont < tolerance 
            break

        currentFont = (minFont + maxFont)/2
        currentWidth = textWithCurrentFont.boundingRect.Width
        n++

    while n <= maxIter

    return currentFont
```

From what I read it should have logarithmic speed, but also I read that it is "slow"

Is there a better way ?

I don't know if I can improve my search by assuming a relationship between font size and font width - definitely there is one, but it's non-linear. So I don't know how to even improve the speed by a better "first guess"

Comment: The relationship between font "size" and font width may not actually be linear, but it will be approximately linear.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm I have tried to just multiply my current font with the reqWidth/curentWidth ratio... the results are way off the scale. The font changes a lot slower. It doesn't help that, based on the text contents, some letters are taking less space than others, so the relationship between font size and text width is affected not only by the amount of text, but also by the actual letters used, as well as font type. That's why I have to approximate.. iterate... guess...

Comment: So if the current box is too large `currentWidth > reqWidth` then you search in the larger interval with `[currentFont, maxFont]`? And if it is too small you search in the smaller interval `[minFont, currentFont]`? Isn't that backwards?

Comment: @dpmcmlxxvi Fixing, thanks - that's what I meant but my subroutine for translating thoughts to pseudocode is buggy

Comment: If you find the width / fontSize ratio is highly nonlinear then I would recommend to check your code. It's only nonlinear if you have a font where for example any fontSize 12 ≤ size < 13 returns the same width. Experiment and print the results. And if you measure a few thousand strings, you will find that for longer strings there is a reasonably strong correlation between number of characters and width.

Comment: Bisection requires that you have the final solution bracketed, but otherwise assumes nothing about the form of the solution.  If you know something about the form of the solution, you also have a way of estimating where to look for the solution.  Use that to guess your new font, rather than just bisecting, and iterate, and you have what numerical analysis people call the "false position method".  (Note: Hamming's "modified false position method" is better.  Newton's method is far better, but you don't have the derivative available.)

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm Mandrill's answer below gives me a way to estimate position, for example using the current font and a font multiplied by size ratios, is that what you mean ? How is Hamming's method ? Indeed no derivative...

Comment: @Thalia, Mandrill's answer describes the false position method.  The modified false position method is a variation on the theme.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method for more information.  (This is why you wanted to take the numerical methods class, although, come to think of it, false position methods are not usually taught these days.)

Comment: What language are you using here? Some languages provide some built-in libraries for lower-level text layout calculations. I have used these to calculate widths and advance widths and scale linearly (although perhaps I haven't had large enough strings to where kerning/numerical errors became a problem). [SFML Glyphs](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Font.php) and [WPF GlyphRuns](https://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/glyphrun-and-so-forth/)

Comment: @JTrana i use Qt... QGraphicTextItem...they provide bounding box but no reverse info

Comment: Looks like you might have access to a corresponding QGlyphRun object with QRawFont also having some good stuff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not going to code it but I will give you a math approach. Assuming you know the resulting width with two different font sizes:
font size 1 (s1) implies text width 1 (w1) (the small value)
font size 2 (s2) implies text width 2 (w2) (the bigger value)
then your linear estimate of size (s3) that will fit the required width (w) is from using manipulating this formula:
(s3-s1)/(s2-s1)=(w-w1)/(w2-w1)
so
estimate correct width is
s3 = s1+(w-w1)*(s2-s1)/(w2-w1)

now you check w3 (the width when using s3). If w < w3 then repeat the method but using s1,w1,s3,w3 if w > w3 then repeat the method but using s3,w3,s2,w2.
This iterative approach only requires that the width for a given text is a monotonic function of the font size, in other words doesn't matter if linear but it will converge faster if the function is closer to linear, so it will accelerate convergence as the range of font sizes reduces.

Comment: Thank you, looks very logical, I will try implementing when I get a chance

Comment: In this answer should font size 2 be using the variables s2, w2?

Comment: Related question: [What kind of transform is this?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/221592/73949)